# Sequlize generate a table with a foreign key while explicitly requested not to

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have the following association in `PersonEntity`:

```
    @HasMany(() => SocialPostEntity, {
        foreignKey: 'parentId',
        foreignKeyConstraint: false,
    })
    posts?: SocialPostEntity[];
```

On the other hand the related column on `SocialPostEntity`:

```
    @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
    parentId: number;
```

The generated create table script has created the `parentId` column with a foreign key to `PersonEntity`. event though I have explicitly mentioned `foreignKeyConstraint: false`

Im not intended to use `synchronize: true` in production but I'm afraid that it means that my mapping is not accurate.

Bottom line I want `parentId` to be a simple integer, that's it.

Thanks

Comment: what is your purpose of `parentId to be a simple integer`  ?

Comment: @MERN this is a loose association, without a foreign key, this is why I did `foreignKeyConstraint: false`